# javaFX webview with openlayers, i drag map tiles "as images" out of the programs screen instead of map dragging

Tags: webview, javafx-8, openlayers-3

I use javaFX 8 with Openlayers 3 in a webview.

Whenever i try to  drag the mouse it works for only a small distance (maybe the tile thats loaded on application start?).

After that i seem to grab the entire map tile image (like you can do e.g. in chrome with normal images) and i can move it out of the application screens border.

Because of this i can not move the map around.

Any idea what could cause this or how i could start debugging? Openlayers inspected via weinre throws no js errors it seems, javaFX itself is completely new to me and i get no default errors as well.

Comment: I noticed the same in my project, it started when updating to OpenLayers 3.1.1. I reverted to OL 3.0.0, this is working as wanted.

Comment: that is good to know, thanks
shouldve tried that before

Comment: btw, this only happens in WebView of JavaFX 8, I use 1.8.0_25; all other browsersare ok. Another thing I notice when using OL 3.1.1 is that the zoom control to zoom out shows as '2' instead of '-'. I can fix that by using '\u2013' instead of the default '\u2212'. This as well only happens in WebView and not in any other browser. Can you reproduce that?

Comment: sry to disappoint but didnt try it any more, using node webkit atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, even when you haven't got the problem any more as you are using different tools, for the record:

What for me seems to be working is to define the `div`for the map with the `ondragstart` handler like this:

```
<div id="map" ondragstart="javascript: return false;"></div>
```

It seems that in OL 3.1.1 sometimes the start of a drag bubbles up to the WebView as it receives a drag detected event and this starts the image drag. This did not happen in OL 3.0.0

Defining the `div` like that helped in my case.